Getting a prometheus gauge's increase in a selected timeframe
I have a gauge metric, posts_total, which has various values:
posts_total{status="v1"} 7788273
posts_total{status="v2"} 320
posts_total{status="v3"} 438131
posts_total{status="v4"} 40
posts_total{status="v5"} 1320

I am trying to get the increase of this value in the range selected by grafana.
Every manual suggests me to use increase(posts_total[$__range]). However, this returns stupidly large results that are obviously wrong: 
Putting aside the question of where it's getting 16M increase from, given that these values change by a few thousands at most every day, and the current value is less than half of that, how can I get the raw increase for these values in a timeframe? For example, if I select "last 1 hour" in the grafana interface, how do I get the raw change for this value in the last 1 hour?
If v2 was at 300 and v4 was at 40 1 hour ago, and now they're respectively at 400 and 44, how do I actually get "100" and "4" (the raw increases in the timeframe) as values for a grafana gauge?

increase should only be used with counters and native histograms  is what the docs states. As you have a gauge, that gauge could go down, in which case prometheus assumes the counter has been reset, and calculates the differenceces - which is why you see silly numbers. So as far as I can see, you can't use increase() on a gauge. I don't know the solution though, possiblysomething like this: https://community.grafana.com/t/solved-display-counter-increase-in-grafana/90283

Nos is correct: increase can only be used with counters and counter like metrics. If your metric is a gauge (which by the way breaks the naming convention with its _total postfix, you should use something else. If all you are interested in is difference between values at start and end you can use delta or metric1 - metric1 offset $__range

Managed to solve it after bashing my head against the wall for a few hours:
To display the change within the selected timeframe, the query is
delta(posts_total{status=~'v2|v4'}[$__range])

